# Как задать время перехода по якорной ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Приветствую!

Не могу понять как замедлить время перехода по якорной ссылке. Допустим мне нужно перейти в третью секцию, но не в долю секунды, а в течение 2х секунд. Как это реализовать.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#anchor3">Переход к 3 секции</a>
<section id="anchor1">
  <h2>Секция 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor2">
  <h2>Секция 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor3">
  <h2>Секция 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor4">
  <h2>Секция 4</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor5">
  <h2>Секция 5</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor6">
  <h2>Секция 6</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor7">
  <h2>Секция 7</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первую очередь вам надо остановить стандартное действие(переход по якорю), после получаете имя `ID` и делайте простую анимацию к точке....

```js
 $(window).load(function () {

  $('a').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
   var anchor = $(this).attr('href').split('#');

   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + anchor[1]).position().top + 'px'
   }, 2000);

  });


 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#anchor3">Переход к 3 секции</a>
<section id="anchor1">
  <h2>Секция 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor2">
  <h2>Секция 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor3">
  <h2>Секция 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor4">
  <h2>Секция 4</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor5">
  <h2>Секция 5</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor6">
  <h2>Секция 6</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor7">
  <h2>Секция 7</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis doloribus pariatur quidem ea cum hic quisquam omnis aut optio nisi quaerat dignissimos ratione provident sequi, aperiam eveniet voluptates perspiciatis fugiat, alias accusantium. Tempora
    eum placeat ullam quisquam molestias? Mollitia voluptates repellendus nostrum magnam quia dolore! Magnam voluptatum eius quas cumque porro culpa sint deleniti, minima, omnis, doloribus reiciendis dolorem iste. Illum nihil nulla ratione quos mollitia
    alias fugit et ipsam aut, voluptatibus eaque velit facere pariatur, culpa officia, in necessitatibus ad ab asperiores debitis explicabo. Voluptates amet ipsam consequatur debitis. Exercitationem officiis quibusdam illo, labore numquam odit dolore
    consequuntur. Tenetur!</p>
</section>
```